# Set labels to column title in a stacked bar graph

Tags: labels, bar-chart

I was trying to build a stacked bar graph which displays the labels of the columns title not in a legend, but directly near the bar itself. So far, I came up with the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotstableread{
Column  abc def ghi
col1    32  2   35
col2    34  54  2
}\MyName
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar=0pt,
ybar stacked,
bar shift=0pt,
xticklabels from table={\MyName}{Column},
xtick=data,
nodes near coords=\col
]
\pgfplotstableforeachcolumn\MyName\as\col{%
    \ifnum\pgfplotstablecol=0 
    \else
    \edef\tmp{%
        \noexpand\addplot table [x expr=\noexpand\coordindex,y=\col] {\noexpand\MyName};
    }%
    \tmp
    \fi
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, in the resulting diagram all labels are set to the last column title, to "ghi", instead of "abc", "def" and "ghi" respectively.
Does anyone have a good idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the problems is that you set `nodes near coords=\col` outside the scope of the loop where `\col` is set.  This happens to interfere with the ticks as well.  What you need to do is set the value used by `nodes near coords` inside the loop.  The key to this is to assign `point meta`.  Usually this expects something that gives a number, but there is (a slightly convoluted) way to provide text via TeX code, by specifying

```
point meta={TeX code symbolic={\edef\pgfplotspointmeta{\col}}}
```

The `TeX code symbolic` option takes some code that should define the command `\pgfplotspointmeta` so it typesets the desired label.  In your case, inside the loop `\col` already does what you want.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\pgfplotstableread{
Column  abc def ghi
col1    32  2   35
col2    34  54  2
}\MyName

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar=0pt,
ybar stacked,
nodes near coords,
bar shift=0pt,
xticklabels from table={\MyName}{Column},
xtick=data,
ymin=0
]
\pgfplotstableforeachcolumn\MyName\as\col{%
    \ifnum\pgfplotstablecol=0 
    \else
    \addplot+[point meta={TeX code symbolic={\edef\pgfplotspointmeta{\col}}}] table [x expr=\coordindex,y=\col] {\MyName};
    \fi}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Note that setting `ymin=0` is necessary to get reasonable placing of the lowest node label.  I used `\addplot+` instead of `\addplot` so that previous options are not overridden.

Comment: That's fantastic, I've been trying to do that for longer than I want to admit. Thank you very much, Andrew!